# Spring Boot (jar) + JSF without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to setup a project with Spring Boot version 2.0.5 and primefaces without using web.xml

I am getting 404 when i type http://localhost:8080/ but http://localhost:8080/product-list.jsf returns jsf page.

it looks my controller doesnt work.

pom.xml

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
>   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>     4.0.0
>
> com.auth0.samples
>     spring-boot-faces
>     1.0-SNAPSHOT     jar
>     spring-boot-faces  Spring Boot
>   sample
>                       org.springframework.boot
>         spring-boot-starter-parent
>         2.0.5.RELEASE
>
> org.springframework.boot
>             spring-boot-starter-web
>
> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <!-- JSF Dependency -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2.9</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2.9</version>
>     </dependency>
>           <!-- Tomcat Embed Dependency -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>         <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>
>           <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
>   </dependency>
>           <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
>   </dependency>
>
>
>   <!-- Database dependencies -->      <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>           <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
>       <version>2.3.4</version>        </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
>       <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>            <version>4.1.2</version>
>   </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
>       <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
>       <version>3.4.1.Final</version>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
>       <artifactId>rewrite-integration-faces</artifactId>
>       <version>3.4.1.Final</version>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
>       <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
>       <version>3.4.1.Final</version>      </dependency>       <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
>       <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
>       <version>6.1</version>      </dependency>               <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>       <version>1.16.16</version>      </dependency>   </dependencies>
> ```
>
> src/main/webapp
>               
>               
>                   src/main/resources
>               
>                            
>                 org.springframework.boot
>                 spring-boot-maven-plugin
>                     
>                       
>                         
>                           repackage
>                         
>                         
>                           com.auth0.samples.bootfaces.Application

mainClass

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletRegistraiton() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet>(new FacesServlet(),
                new String[] { "*.jsf" });
        registration.setName("Faces Servlet");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
        return servletContext -> {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@Scope (value = "session")
@Component (value = "productList")
@ELBeanName(value = "productList")
@Join(path = "/", to = "/product-list.jsf")
public class ProductListController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private List<Product> products;
    @Deferred
    @RequestAction
    @IgnorePostback
    public void loadData() {
        products = productRepository.findAll();
    }
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}
```

I found joinfaces for spring boot jsf integration but i dont want to add another dependency to project.

Is there a way to succeed it in anyway?

Comment: Have you looked at JoinFaces https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces ? They have solved all of these problem already with Spring Boot Starters!

Comment: As i mentioned above i know joinfaces

Comment: But the whole point of JoinFaces and Spring Boot is to solve exactly this problem.  Giving you all the right wiring and dependencies so you don't need to figure this out.  But you can just look at what they do in their PrimeFaces starter and work backwards.